# F# workflow builder for Rx

Tags: f#, system.reactive, using, computation-expression

There's a nice F# workflow builder for Rx here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2011/05/30/nice-f-syntax-for-rx-reactive-extensions.aspx

I've been trying to make a Using implementation for the workflow but keep banging my head against the wall. Maybe it's too late here.

How would one create this?

```
type RxBuilder () =

    // ...

    member this.Using (disposable, f) =
        Observable.Using(???)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, the original code needs to be updated slightly for the latest Rx releases. Namely, `For` and `While` should be implemented as:

```
member this.For (xs : 'a seq, f: 'a -> 'b IObservable) =
    Observable.SelectMany(xs.ToObservable(), new Func<_, IObservable<_>>(f)) 

member this.While (f, xs: 'a IObservable) =
    Observable.TakeWhile (xs, new Func<_,bool>(fun _ -> f()))
```

Then, based on [this](https://github.com/panesofglass/FSharp.Reactive/blob/master/src/Observable.fs), you can use the following for an implementation of `Using`:

```
member this.Using(res:#IDisposable, body) = this.TryFinally(body res, fun () -> match res with null -> () | disp -> disp.Dispose())
```

Comment: Nice! I like the constraint notation. It looks like one should take a closer look at fsharpx.

Comment: My implementation of For actually looked like this:     member this.For (xs : 'a IObservable, f: 'a -> 'b IObservable) : 'b IObservable =
        xs.SelectMany(f). Not tested yet tho.

Comment: That's basically the same thing, I just didn't use the extension method format for style reasons (to match the other implementations), and the explicit type arguments in order to confirm everything worked as expected.